# PowerShell on MaxOs versionInfo is empty

Tags: python, macos, powershell, winapi, versioninfo

I need to get the versionInfo of a windows executable with a Python script running on MacOS. Since Winapi is not available on MacOS, I found that the way to do is via powershell commands. Installed it via brew as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-macos?view=powershell-7.1). pwsh is running after that.

using Get-Item or Get-ItemProperty with the exe on MacOS does return a value but the ProductionVersion and FileVersion are empty:

```
PS /Users/test>$m = Get-Item /Users/test/test.exe       
PS /Users/test>echo  $m                                                                                                

    Directory: /Users/test

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-----          04/29/2021    14:14        1045616 test.exe

PS /Users/test> $m.VersionInfo

ProductVersion   FileVersion      FileName
--------------   -----------      --------
                                 /Users/test/test.exe
```

running the same command on the same file on Windows does return both values.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative for using winapi on MacOS to work with win exe?

Comment: So, I believe there is no way a macOS can get a Windows exe version. 
It was answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1004403/find-exe-file-version-of-a-file-in-osx

Comment: thanks @GrzegorzOchlik, that is exactly where I found to use the Powershell option :) but the results are empty strings :/